# logical error in linear search in python

Tags: python-3.x

my code to search for an element entered by the user among the list also entered by the user always shows "element not found", even if the user enters an element in the list entered. what is the error? 
also, is there something wrong with my break syntax?

```
       x=eval(input("list  :    "))
       x=list(x)
       n=len(x)
       i=0
       ele=input("enter element to be searched :    ")

       for i in range(0,n):
             if(x[i]==ele):
                  print("element found at index number ",i)
                  break

       else:
             print("element not found")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rightly pointed out by @arewm there is a type mismatch but also here is an alternate solution that has clean way to implement the list from user input:

```
strInput=input("list  :    ")
x=strInput.split()
x=[int(a) for a in x]
n=len(x)
i=0
ele=input("enter element to be searched :    ")
ele=int(ele)
for i in range(0,n):
    if(x[i]==ele):
        print("element found at index number ",i)
        break
    else:
        print("element not found")
```

Output:

```
list  :     1 2 3 4
enter element to be searched :     1
element found at index number  0
```

Edit: Also, if you would like `element not found` to appear only once here is a simple change:

```
strInput=input("list  :    ")
x=strInput.split()
x=[int(a) for a in x]
n=len(x)
i=0
ele=input("enter element to be searched :    ")
ele=int(ele)
for i in range(0,n):
    if(x[i]==ele):
        print("element found at index number ",i)
        break
    if(i==n-1):
        print("element not found")
```

Ouput:

```
list  :     1 2 3 4 5 7 6 88 9
enter element to be searched :     5
element found at index number  4
```

Comment: thanks,it worked.
could you tell me what went wrong in my code and where?

Comment: I tried printing list with your implementation and doesn't seem to convert it the way you are expecting. Also, the type mismatch was problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a type mismatch. Since the list is evaluated, numerical items will not be strings. The element to search for, however, is a string.

Converting the element to a string before comparison can fix this.

```
x=eval(input("list  :    "))
x=list(x)
ele=input("enter element to be searched :    ")
i=0

for e in x:
    if str(e) == ele:
        print("element found at index number ",i)
        break

    else:
        print("element not found")
    i+=1
```

Comment: i did this,..but it still shows "element not found" four times,::::::

D:\pcodes>python linearsearch.py
list: 1,4,2,3,6,5,7,8,9
enter element to be searched :   3
element not found
element not found
element not found
element found at index number 3